# Wordpress redirect folder to subdomain

Tags: wordpress

I have recently redone my website in wordpress and moved it to a different server.

I need `www.example.com/releases` to point to another IP.

I have set `releases.example.com` to point to this IP.

So I'd now like when someone browses to `www.example.com/releases` for the user to be redirected to `releases.example.com/releases`.

The reason we need this to happen is our software automatically checks that folder for new releases (and we don't want to have to update that part of the code).

Answer (score 1):

To redirect all requests for `example.com/releases` to `releases.example.com/releases` (and all requests within), place the following near the top of the .htaccess file (below `RewriteEngine On`) in the document root of the *main domain*:

```
RewriteRule ^releases.* http://releases.example.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

This does assume that you don't have any other URLs that start "releases" in the root of the main domain. `$0` corresponds to the entire pattern that is matched (the entire URL-path).

I've used mod_rewrite (as opposed to a mod_alias `Redirect`) since WordPress also uses mod_rewrite for rewriting and it's not good to mix the two.